# Using VS Code to Cross Compile and Program in Yocto Project

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, yocto

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 running from Docker container on windows with WSL2 backend. Now I want to use VS Code inside docker container to cross-compile applications. I have setup the toolchain and built SDK from my yocto image. And then tried to install VS Code from snap. Since snap was not installed, I installed it with snapd. Then when I run `sudo snap install --classic code` I get the following error:

```
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/code: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

For `sudo systemctl start snapd.service` I get the below response:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Since there is no `systemd` on WSL I cannot execute `systemctl`.

Can anyone please let me know how to install and run VS Code inside docker container?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using Remote connection from VS Code instead of installing VS Code from snap in Ubuntu. VS Code comes with a feature to connect with Docker Containers using Remote Connection option. From the VS Code select the option `Attach to Running Container` by selection below from bottom left corner.

[image: WSL Connection]